# Cannot add data-toggle with prop()

Tags: jquery, html

I use bootstrap framework. In a function I have

```
$('<button>').prop('data-toggle','dropdown')
.prop('type',"button")
.prop('class',"btn btn-icon")
.prop('id',"btn"+i)            .append($('<img>')
.prop('src',"../resource/images/icons/add.png")))
```

but in html it shows

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-icon dropdown" >
<img src="../resource/images/icons/add.png"></button>
```

Comment: You mind elaborating on your issue before you get down-voted by everyone here? What's not working? Are there any errors in console? etc....etc...

Comment: It's a bit too vague. you need to elaborate more on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your data attribute in this fashion:

```
$('button').attr('data-toggle', 'dropdown').prop...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set and get data attributes/values using the jQuery .data() method:

```
$('button').data('toggle','dropdown').prop(....)...
```